# mongo aggregation operator $push on cosmodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, azure-cosmosdb

I am using azure cosmodb (vCore cluster, MongoDB version 6.0) to deploy a mongodb database, the error occurs when I try to do an aggregation using $group, in my local database the aggregation works correctly but in cosmo I have the following error.

```
 { '$group': { '_id': '$_id', 'tags': { '$push': '$tags' } } }
```

**"Accumulator $push not implemented yet"**

I don't know if there is a solution to use this operator with Azure Cosmo or if there is an alternative in Azure that allows it to be done (hopefully in the free tier).

Aggregation pipeline

```
[{$unwind: {
 path: '$tags'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'tags',
 localField: 'tags.tag',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'tags.tag'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$tags.tag'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'taglevels',
 localField: 'tags.level',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'tags.level'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$tags.level'
}}, {$group: {
 _id: '$_id',
 tags: {
  $push: '$tags'
 }
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'users',
 localField: '_id',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'user'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$user'
}}, {$addFields: {
 'user.tags': '$tags'
}}, {$replaceRoot: {
 newRoot: '$user'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'seniorities',
 localField: 'seniority',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'seniority'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$seniority'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'availabilities',
 localField: 'availability',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'availability'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$availability'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'availabilitytypes',
 localField: 'availabilityType',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'availabilityType'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$availabilityType'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'userstatuses',
 localField: 'status',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'status'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$status'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'countries',
 localField: 'country',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'country'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$country'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'countries',
 localField: 'nacionality',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'nacionality'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$nacionality'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'profiletypes',
 localField: 'profile',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'profile'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$profile'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'workmodalities',
 localField: 'workModalities',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'workModalities'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'roles',
 localField: 'roles',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'roles'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'saastags',
 localField: 'saasTags',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'saasTags'
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'profesionaltags',
 localField: 'profesionalTags',
 foreignField: '_id',
 as: 'profesionalTags'
}}]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarify that you're running MongoDB API of Cosmos DB (vs, say, MongoDB vCore). Also, which MongoDB compatibility version did you select (assuming you're using MongoDB API)? Please edit accordingly. And also, please include a small bit of sample data, along with your fully query/aggregation call.

Comment: you should remember that `cosmos db` and `mongo db` are different databases, so a lot of things that are supported in mongo db (especially that are released after v4.2, but not only) are not supported by cosmos db

Answer (score 0):

`cosmosdb` works close (in some/most of cases) but not exactly the same as `mongodb` itself. So, even though `$push` is a native mongo operator and you can call it for cosmos via Mongo API, it doesn't mean that cosmos supports it in all cases (you can find out it in each particular case only after try). In this particular case, the error says that it's not supported. Based on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-42#accumulator-expressions). It looks like it's supported in some cases, but probably not inside `$group`.

Comment: Note that this is why I asked the OP to clarify. That article you linked to points to v3.2 compatibility documentation. There's also v3.6, 4.0, and 4.2.

Comment: good point, link updated